# .push() value to JavaScript array (n) times using .fill()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to `.push()` a value to an array but replicate the pushed value `n` times without using a traditional loop to perform the replication? For instance using `.fill()`. The examples I have seen declare a `new Array()` with a length of `n`, and `.fill()` it with a value. However, I have not seen any examples dealing with `.push()`, so I'm not even sure it is possible.

Example of what I'm looking for:

```
var my_array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    my_array.push(5);
};
```

Scenario:

I'm pulling values from three different arrays or objects to populate a single matrix that will be ran through a Munkres (Hungarian) algorithm, in order to avoid introducing another loop I would like to `.push` values to the matrix and use `.fill()` to repeat the value `n` times.

Example:

```
var s = […];
var a = […];
var p = […];

var matrix = [];
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    var preferences = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < p.length; j++ {
        var pid = p[j];
        for (var k = 0; k < a.length; k++ {
            if (pid == a[k]) {
                for (var l = 0; l < 5; l++) {  // <-- THIS.
                    preferences.push(a[k]);
                };
            };
        };
    };
    matrix.push(preferences);
};
```

Comment: I think you need to use `fill`, but without `push` - `push` returns the new length of the array.

Comment: The problem is I need to `append` the values to the `preferences` array so they are retained each iteration. I think if I create an array with the desired values and `.push()` that to the `preferences` array it would result in `[[ ],[ ],[ ]]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `concat` and `fill`:

```
preferences = preferences.concat(Array(5).fill(a[k]));
```

Comment: The difference here is that push would directly mutate the array, but concat will not. It seems like array mutation is desired based on the question

Comment: This is resulting in an empty array after the loop finishes.

Comment: Sorry @artomason - try `preferences = preferences.concat(Array(5).fill(a[k]));`.

Comment: That worked. If you update your answer I will accept it.

Comment: No worries @artomason - I'll add it into my answer. If my answer fixed your problem , please mark it as accepted.